# multiple events from one control

Tags: javafx, actionlistener, scenebuilder

Working with a login control (username and password) I can press enter on the control and then tab (without entering anything) and I get the warning that says to enter a valid user name. This is the desired effect, however if I just tab or click out of the field the event does not trigger, nor does the cursor move to the next field if the user enters a username and just presses enter.  Any suggestions?

Controller Code

```
    void getUserName(ActionEvent event) {
    userName.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
        if (!(userName.getText().isEmpty())) {
            if (!newV) {
                String textUserValue = userName.getText();
                warningLabel.setVisible(false);
                userPwd.requestFocus();
            }
        } else {
            warningLabel.setText("Please enter a valid user name");
            warningLabel.setVisible(true);
            warningLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-font-size: 12;");
            userName.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}

@FXML
void pwdController(ActionEvent event) {
    userPwd.focusedProperty().addListener((ov, oldV, newV) -> {
        if (!newV) {
            if (!(userPwd.getText().isEmpty())) {
                String textPwdValue = userPwd.getText();
                warningLabel.setVisible(false);
                String uName = userName.getText();
                ServiceWrapper.conn1(uName, textPwdValue);
                srcUpi.setDisable(false);
                tgtUpi.setDisable(false);
                mrgEqstDt.setDisable(false);
                userName.setDisable(true);
                userPwd.setDisable(true);
                srcUpi.requestFocus();
            }
        } else {
            warningLabel.setText("Please enter a valid password");
            warningLabel.setVisible(true);
            warningLabel.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: red; -fx-font-size: 12;");
            userPwd.requestFocus();
        }
    });
}
```

FXML Code

```
<TextField fx:id="userName" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#getUserName" onMouseReleased="#getUserName" promptText="User Name" />
<Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="42.0" text="User Name" />
<TextField fx:id="userPwd" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="72.0" nAction="#pwdController" promptText="Password" />
<Label layoutX="15.0" layoutY="100.0" text="Password" />
<Label fx:id="warningLabel" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="15.0" layoutY="138.0" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="170.0" text="securitywarning" visible="false" />
<Separator layoutY="168.0" prefHeight="7.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
```

Comment: Just register the listeners on the focused properties in the `initialize()` method, instead of in an action handler.

Comment: I am new to JavaFX and SceneBuilder.  Not sure what you mean as I do not see an intialize() method in any of the classes.

Comment: Put an `initialize()` (not "intialize") method in your controller. See examples in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers).